# Порпорционально отмасштабировать любой контент внутри блока DIV

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Допустим есть некоторый контент (с дивами, картинками, тестом, фреймами и т.п.). Существует ли способ в котором можно было поместить его в DIV-блок и при задании особого стиля этому блоку, пропорционально масштабировать его содержимое по ширине и высоте (выглядеть все это должно как будто мы масштабируем растровую картинку)?

Comment: Ну как пример стиль может менять высоту/длинну родительского блока. Внутренние элементы должны быть зависимы от этого значения и будут соответственно меняться. Однако для эффекта масштабирования (т.е. пропорционального изменения коэфициента от 100% размера) как по мне без js выполнить весьма тяжко (ну разве что кучу transformation внутри). С помощью переменных и функции css3 можно много чего вытворить, но также многое придется учесть и сложнее потом поддерживать.

Comment: @alexoander , о родительском блоке не идет речь, я имел ввиду менять масштаб вложенного контента внутри блока, я не очень силен в css , просто может есть какой то хак или там всякие вебкиты и тп.

Comment: Я под родительским блоком имел ввиду тот, в котором будут все "масштабируемые элементы". Простого решения тут 100% нет (т.е. нет волшебного хака, который превратит DOM в картинку на время масштабирования и обратно =) )

Comment: @alexoander я просил из html-элементов сделать картинку? по моему нет...

Comment: Забудь про картинку, это просто пример. Масштабирование есть изменение размеров чего либо относительно 100% их размера. По сути - это математическая задача, суть которой сводится к изменению значений элементов относительно их 100%. Вот только в css для этого придется изрядно попотеть (особенно если элементов много). В JS это типичная задача на расчеты, но может превратиться в достаточно тяжелую по скорости исполнения (опять же из-за кол-ва элементов).

Comment: @alexoander ну есть же там всякие единицы EM и REM и свойство inherit может кто знает что нибудь похожее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Задавайте для этого блока и его содержимого всё в `rem` вместо `px`. Затем меняйте значение `font-size` для тэга `html`.

Единицы измерения rem — это root em, то есть вы задаёте все размеры относительно `font-size` `html`. Таким способом очень легко программировать. Если для `html` `font-size: 16px` (обычно это значение по умолчанию), то `1rem` = `16px`, `0.5rem` = `8px` и т.д. То есть вы просто делите значения пикселов на `16`. При этом эти единицы измерения широко поддерживается браузерами (IE9+).

Пример:

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.resizable {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border: 0.25rem solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$(`html`).css('font-size', parseInt($(`html`).css('font-size')) - 1)">
-
</button>

<button onclick="$(`html`).css('font-size', parseInt($(`html`).css('font-size')) + 1)">
+
</button>

<div class="resizable">
Это масштабируемый текст
</div>
```

Comment: похоже на правду. и спасибо за бонус ) не знал что к тегу html можно применять стили.